# Реализовать разветвление в зависимости от типа T шаблонной функции

Tags: c++

Помогите правильно реализовать функцию. Есть шаблонная функция template  void editRecord(list &data), которая изменяет конкретные поля объекта списка. У меня есть два списка list и list. В зависимости от выбора пользователя, один из них будет передан в функцию. В объектов типа ShootWeapon и ColdWeapon есть как общие унаследованные, так и уникальные поля. Мне нужно в самой функции реализовать разветвление if-else, которое обеспечит отдельную логику для list и list и предоставит возможность изменять уникальные поля каждого списка. Пробовал реализовать через typeid(T) == typeid(my_type) и итератор typename list::iterator it, но получаю ошибки

```
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\source.cpp(132): error C2039: 'SetType': is not a member of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\shootweapon.h(9): note: see declaration of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\source.cpp(137): error C2039: 'SetLength': is not a member of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\shootweapon.h(9): note: see declaration of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\source.cpp(142): error C2039: 'SetHardness': is not a member of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\shootweapon.h(9): note: see declaration of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\source.cpp(147): error C2039: 'SetConstruction': is not a member of 'ShootWeapon'
1>e:\courseproj\courseproj\shootweapon.h(9): note: see declaration of 'ShootWeapon'
```

Только начал работать с итераторами и шаблонными функциями. Предполагаю, что неправильно использую итератор. Помогите разобраться и решить проблему. Заранее благодарен.

```
template <class T> void editRecord(list<T> &data)
{
    if (!data.empty())
    {
        typename list<T>::iterator it;
        int el, action, iTemp, strTemp, dbTemp;
        do
        {
            cout << "Введите номер елемента, который хотите изменить" << endl;
            cin >> el;
            if (el > 0 && el <= data.size())
            {
                advance(it.begin(), el - 1);
                do
                {
                    cout << "Какое поле вы хотели бы изменить?" << endl
                        << "1. Серийный номер оружия" << endl
                        << "2. Название оружия" << endl
                        << "3. Вес оружия" << endl
                        << "4. Изготовитель оружия" << endl;

                    if (typeid(T) == typeid(ColdWeapon))
                    {
                        cout << "5. Тип холодного оружия" << endl
                            << "6. Длина клинка холодного оружия" << endl
                            << "7. Твердость клинка холодного оружия" << endl
                            << "8. Конструкция рукоятки холодного оружия" << endl;
                    }
                    else if (typeid(T) == typeid(ShootWeapon))
                    {
                        cout << "5. Вес пули огнестрельного оружия" << endl
                            << "6. Скорость пули огнестрельного оружия" << endl
                            << "7. Убойная дальность огнестрельного оружия" << endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Логика для этого типа не реализована" << endl;
                        return;
                    }
                    cin >> action;
                    switch (action)
                    {
                    case 1:
                        cout << "Введите новое значение серийного номера оружия: ";
                        cin >> strTemp;
                        (*it).SetNumber(strTemp);
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        cout << "Введите новое название оружия: ";
                        cin >> strTemp;
                        (*it).SetName(strTemp);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cout << "Введите новое значение веса оружия: ";
                        cin >> dbTemp;
                        (*it).SetWeight(dbTemp);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        cout << "Введите нового изготовителя оружия: ";
                        cin >> strTemp;
                        (*it).SetManufacturer(strTemp);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        cout << "Введите новое значение убойного действия оружия: ";
                        cin >> dbTemp;
                        (*it).SetCasualtyProducingEffect(dbTemp);
                    }

                    if (typeid(T) == typeid(ColdWeapon))
                    {
                        switch (action)
                        {
                        case 6:
                            cout << "Введите новый тип холодного оружия: ";
                            cin >> strTemp;
                            (*it).SetType(strTemp);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            cout << "Введите новую длину клинка холодного оружия: ";
                            cin >> iTemp;
                            (*it).SetLength(iTemp);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            cout << "Введите новое значение твердости клинка холодного оружия: ";
                            cin >> iTemp;
                            (*it).SetHardness(iTemp);
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            cout << "Введите новое значение конструкции рукоятки холодного оружия: ";
                            cin >> strTemp;
                            (*it).SetConstruction(strTemp);
                            break;
                        default:
                            cout << "Такого пункта меню для холодного оружия нету" << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        switch (action)
                        {
                        case 6:
                            cout << "Введите новое значение веса пули: ";
                            cin >> dbTemp;
                            (*it).SetBulletWeight(dbTemp);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            cout << "Введите новое значение скорости пули: ";
                            cin >> iTemp;
                            (*it).SetBulletSpeed(iTemp);
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            cout << "Введите новое значение убойной дальности пули: ";
                            cin >> iTemp;
                            (*it).SetBulletSpeed(iTemp);
                            break;
                        default:
                            cout << "Такого пункта меню для огнестрельного оружия нету" << endl;
                        }
                    }
                } while (action < 1 || (typeid(T) == typeid(ShootWeapon) && action > 8) || (typeid(T) == typeid(ColdWeapon) && action > 9));
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Такого элемента не существует" << endl;
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "В масиве отсутствуют элементы" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Эти "спагетти" следует убирать путем наследования разных классов оружия от одного общего или **перегрузкой** функции для разных типов (**специализация** функций - вещь, мягко говоря, не рекомендуемая).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы можете использовать C++11, то с помощью [is_same](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) это делается следующим образом

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T> void editRecord(list<T> &data)
{
    if (std::is_same<T, ColdWeapon>::value) { /* ... */ }  
}
```

Отмечу, что использование таких проверок в шаблонных методах это плохой дизайн кода. Лучше использовать [механизм специализации шаблонов](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) для конкретных типов

```
// общая шаблонная функция
template <class T> void editRecord(list<T> &data)
{
}
// шаблонная функция, где T является ColdWeapon 
template <> void editRecord(list<ColdWeapon> &data)
{
    // реализация поведения функции для данного типа
}
```

*Спасибо за ремарку @HolyBlackCat для С++17*

Так как `is_same` может быть вычислена во время компиляции и преобразована в константу, то более эффективно использовать вместо обычного `if` оператор `if constexpr`. Тем самым, уже на этапе компиляции будут отброшена та ветка условия, которая никогда не будет выполняться.

```
template <class T> void editRecord(list<T> &data)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same<T, ColdWeapon>::value) { /* ... */ }  
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Не знал, что это плохой дизайн кода. Очень помогли.

Comment: Начиная с С++17 лучше использовать `if constexpr (...) {...}`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо за дополнение.