# Ошибка ветвления в шаблонной функции

Tags: c++, c++11, шаблоны-с++, vector, типы-данных

```
template <typename matrix_type, typename list_type>
void matrix_to_list(matrix_type& matrix, list_type& list)
{
    if (list.size() == 0) 
        list = list_type(matrix.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j])
            {
                if (is_same< list_type, vector< vector< pair<int, int> > > >::value)
                    list[i].push_back(pair<int, int>(j, matrix[i][j]));
                else
                    list[i].push_back(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пишу функцию преобразования матрицы смежности в список смежности (для графов). Т.к. для взвешенных и невзвешенных графов списки смежности имеют разные типы (vector< vector< int > > и vector< vector< pair< int, int > > >), но в целом схема перехода из матрицы в список практически идентична, захотелось написать одну шаблонную функцию, вместо перегрузок.
Однако компилятор ругается:

```
Ошибка C2664 "void std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>::push_back(_Ty &&)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "std::pair<int,int>" в "const int &"
```

Можно ли что-то с этим сделать или лучше написать перегрузку?
(P.S. сначала я в функцию передавал флаг weighted и ветвление делал от него и изначально шел именно с этим вопросом, но stackoverflow предложил вот [это решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825322/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-t-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8), но оно не помогло).
Пишу в Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: А что не так с `if constexpr`, который по ссылке упоминается? Или вам нужно именно в С++11 это сделать?

Comment: Visual Studio ругается на использование C++17. Я сейчас пробую решить эту проблему, но хотелось бы стандарт не позже C++14, ибо не все тестирующие системы на контестах принимают новый стандарт.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для эмулирования поведения `if constexpr` в более старых версиях стандарта можно написать шаблон функции с частичными специализациями. Для эмулирования частичных специализаций для шаблонов функций (которые до сих пор запрещены) можно написать шаблон класса со статической функцией:

```
template <typename matrix_type, typename list_type, typename x_enabled = void> class
push_to_list_impl final
{
    public: static void
    Do(size_t const i, size_t const j, matrix_type const & matrix, list_type & list)
    {
         list[i].emplace_back(j);
    }
};

template <typename matrix_type, typename list_type> class
push_to_list_impl
<
    matrix_type
,   list_type
,   typename ::std::enable_if
    <
        ::std::is_same
        <
            list_type
        ,   ::std::vector<::std::vector<::std::pair<int, int>>>   
        >::value          
    >::type
> final
{
    public: static void
    Do(size_t const i, size_t const j, matrix_type const & matrix, list_type & list)
    {
         list[i].emplace_back(j, matrix[i][j]);
    }
};
```

…

```
if (matrix[i][j])
{
    push_to_list_impl<matrix_type, list_type>::Do(i, j, list, matrix);
}
```

Comment: Решение конечно очень классное и хитрое, спасибо, заодно узнал такой интересный прием. Правда наверно в данном конкретном случае быстрее и компактнее написать перегрузку. Без if constexpr не работает, как я понимаю, потому что на этапе компиляции list_type неизвестен и компилятор пытается подставить list в обе ветки?

Comment: @ВладСивирин `list_type`, как и любой другой параметр шаблона, известен на этапе компиляции. Без использования `if constexpr` обе ветки будут компилироваться. При известном результате `is_same...` вторая ветка потенциально может быть оптимизирована, но она все равно должна корректно компилироваться. Другими словами, с `if constexpr` сначала одна ветка отбрасывается, а потом оставшаяся компилируется, а без него обе ветки компилируются, и только потом одна из них может быть отброшена во имя оптимальности.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли с пониманием :)

Answer (score 2):

```
template <typename matrix_type, typename list_type>
void matrix_to_list(const matrix_type& matrix, list_type& list)
{
```

функция не модифицирует  matrix, потому нужно передавать его как константный. Дальше:

```
if (list.size() == 0) 
    list = list_type(matrix.size());
```

Здесь вы  игнорируете имеющийся список(последовательность), присвоив его обьект с размером матрицы, и  весь этот список не инициализируете, а ...

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix.size(); ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); ++j)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j])
        {
            if (is_same< list_type, vector< vector< pair<int, int> > > >::value)
                list[i].push_back(pair<int, int>(j, matrix[i][j]));
            else
                list[i].push_back(j);
```

добавляете в конец  имеющийся неинициализированной списке еще  `matrix.size() *  matrix[i].size()`

Т.е. если матрица имеет размер `n*m`, то у вас получится список  размера `n*m + n*m*m`, где  первые `n*m`  неинициализированные, а значения остальных не то что вам нужно...
Все нужно исправить.

Во вторых, смысль этой шаблонной функции непонятен, поскольку ваша матрица должна содержать элементы только одного типа(типа `int`).  Передать в шаблонную функцию контейнер, содержащийся элементы с типом отличающимся от `int` или `pair<int, int>` вы не сможете. Лучше уж иметь пару перегруженных функций или  подойти к вопросу с точки зрения  иерархии классов. Или же написать шаблонную функцию,  и ее частичную специализацию.

Comment: По поводу передачи matrix как константу согласен, спасибо. Но со списком вы неправы. Список смежности - двумерный vector< vector< int > > , я писал об этом. Каждый вложенный vector[i] исходного vector'а - список вершин, в которые существует путь из i-ой вершины. Поэтому мне нужно сначала проинициализировать list количеством вершин у всего графа, а потом уже для каждой вершины добавлять исходящие из нее другие вершины. Я тестировал эту функцию и она работает, как ожидается (кроме ветвления, в котором у меня возник вопрос). Перегрузить, безусловно, могу, просто было интересно сделать иначе.

Comment: тогда, тем более  вам  нужна специализация шаблона только для готовых списков , уже имеющие matrix.size()  количество элементов, а не  присваивать в функции.   У вас может и работать, если  как  list_type  вы передадите вами написанный  специальный тип.  Но  в таком  случаи как шаблонная функция, ваша функция  еще больше теряет смысль..